# How can i set an onclick for imageview to display full image?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview

I have a code which dynamically adds images and imageviews to my app. I want to set an onClick for all imageviews so that when each image is clicked, the image is displayed in full like how when you click on a facebook image it opens up and you can click next and previous.I have seen alot of other questions and answers but none of them fit what i am looking for.

```
 final int[] images = { R.drawable.abi1, R.drawable.abi2, R.drawable.abi3,
            R.drawable.abi4 };

    LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomView);

    for (int x = 0; x < images.length; x++) {
        final Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                images[x]);

        int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
        int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
        int newWidth = 200;
        int newHeight = 200;

        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        matrix.postRotate(0);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width,
                height, matrix, true);
        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                resizedBitmap);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setPadding(2, 0, 9, 5);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
        imageView.setTag(x);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        linearLayout1.addView(imageView);
    }
```

Comment: You are already setting OnClickListener on imageView. Can you be more specific about your problem? Are you asking how to implement onClick() method to show image in fullscreen?

Comment: Since you have OnClickListener (As Loop stated), you can always make custom "popup", where the clicked image has been showed and then add your own next/prev button what will show next/prev image, if there is one. But I agree with Loop, you should explain a bit better, what is the problem?

Comment: @Loop I am asking how to implement the onClick() listener for the images so it would do exactly as Elven stated

Comment: @Elven yeah...that is what i am asking...how do i implement the popup??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `onClick()` method you can start new activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourFullScreenActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("selected_image", int imageResourceId);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your new activity use ViewPager to show images in fullscreen. ViewPager will let you switch to next image. There is a lot of tutorials about implementing ViewPager.
Notice that within intent I am passing "selected_image" extra. Your new activity can use it to show immediately selected image.

By the way, with your code you can have out of memory errors if you have very high resolution images. This site http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html explain how to load bitmaps efficiently. In case you are showing only images from your app resource folder you could skip loading bitmaps at all. Just call `setImageResource()`, set size with `setLayoutParams()` and `setScaleType()` if needed. Android system will scaled them for you.

Comment: Thanks i got it but then now that i have implemented my fullscreen activity, how do i add image resources from my activity class to my pager class since i added resources dynamically?? Anyway maybe i'll ask that as a whole nother question. Thanks anyway

Comment: I guess you are downloading these images and store on filesystem. If so, you should have Uris for each file. If you do, simply use that Uri as identifier instead resource id. Your adapter would store a list of Uris and load bitmaps whenever view is created.